# How to get fetch particular key from map in Riak?

Tags: riak

I can't seem to find out how to fetch a particular key(register, flag, counter or set) from **within a map** data type in Riak. Is this even possible? Or do I always need to fetch the entire map into my application layer?

I was thinking there would be something similar to an `hget` in redis, where I can fetch a particular key inside a hash (as opposed to doing an `hgetall`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to fetch a particular field from within a map data type in Riak. You can *set* or *update* particular field inside a map, but you can't *fetch* them. All you can do is fetch the entire value

see the [documentation](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/references/protocol-buffers/dt-map-store/)